# How to create dynamic array in c++ which will decide its size at a time of execution?

Tags: c++

**> I found below solution but still user have to enter how many digits

> he/she will enter.For example if user enters 4 digit code then array
>   size should automatically be 4.**

```
int* a = NULL;   // Pointer to int, initialize to nothing.
int n;           // Size needed for array
cin >> n;        // Read in the size
a = new int[n];  // Allocate n ints and save ptr in a.
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    a[i] = 0;    // Initialize all elements to zero.
}
. . .  // Use a as a normal array
delete [] a;  // When done, free memory pointed to by a.
a = NULL;     // Clear a to prevent using invalid memory reference.
```

Comment: much simpler: `std::vector<int> a(n);`

Comment: If you want to avoid the user entering the size of the array, then just use a vector. However, the phrasing of your question still makes it seem unclear what your goal actually is.

Comment: This could be ostensibly over-design but if this is part of a large project then consider using boost spirit to parse the input values. The above code then becomes a one-liner when read into a `std::vector<int>`! But certainly use `std::vector<int>` in this case.

Comment: *I found below solution* -- I suggest you look in better places for solutions.  The #1 answer is use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

While your question is somewhat unclear, here is what I take away. The user has to keep entering digits, and suppose the user enters 4 digits, then an array of 4 integers should be created. To emulate this, a good option would be to use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), like the following:

```
std::vector<int> a;
for (int x; std::cin >> x;)
{
    a.push_back(x); // push_back adds a new element to the vector.
}
```

This simplifies your code greatly and prevents you from manually dealing with pointers.

If your goal was to instead directly read a one integer from which you want to extract digits, you can do the following:

```
int input = 0;
std::cin >> input;
std::string inputString = std::to_string(input);

std::vector<int> a;

for (const auto& digit : inputString)
{ 
    a.push_back(std::atoi(digit)); // Convert and add the digit to the vector
}
```

Comment: I think OP wants to enter a four digit code directly, i.e. like `1234` and not individual digits.

Comment: @Rakete1111 made the changes

Comment: You might want to check if the user really inputs a digit :) One way: Read an integer and convert it to string

Comment: @Rakete1111 did that too.